# NES has trouble reading games due to minor damage

Tags: hardware, nes

I just replaced my NES 72-Pin connector and cleaned my game cartridge and my game seems to not go in all the way. I plug it in, and the screen is green or some other color. When I put my finger on the game, and move it to the right just a hair, the NES is able to read the game, but the "textures" are messed up on-screen.

When I try to press the cartridge down, it seems that there is some sort of plastic "pole" that is bent and almost presses against the loading tray as I push it down. Would this be the reason that the game is just out of place for it to function properly?

Comment: Afaik your nes is damaged. Isnt there a way you can shift the cartridge so it works properly?  If so,  you can put some paper in there so it stays in position.  Otherwise wait for some other answer or try to bend the pin straight again with the risk of breaking it.

Comment: Sounds like there is a bum pin or an alignment issue. If you trust that the connector is pristine. I would try very carefully trouble shooting it while it is open. I have known NES' to be finicky.  Had one that would only function if the plastic top shell was removed.

Comment: Had several cartridges on my NES take several times ejecting and reinserting until it registered. The NES is a good system, but can be cumbersome, at times.

Answer (score -1):

When you replace the NES 72-pin connector It'll be hard to insert the game especially the first time, it'll take a few uses before it loosens up.  Use a third party cartridge to shove in there or take the top off and the heat shield and try and insert it then this is what i had to-do when i first did my NES for a while.

Comment: Can you summarise the link? Links answers are generally discouraged, as thry rely on the link working, both now and in the future.